# How do I change the default font of Microsoft OneNote from Calibri to some other font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-onenote-2013

I find **Microsoft OneNote** to be among the best notes taking/organizing apps I have used. I am currently using MS OneNote 2013 (that ships with **MS Office 2013**).

One annoying bit though is the fact that I cannot change the default font. I have to re-select another font every time I create a new note or page. Even when I change the font of some text block on the page, clicking another area on the same page to add a new text block formats the text in Calibri again.

> How can I configure it to switch to my desired font every time I create a new text block on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: start onenote
2: upper left corner of screen left click "file"
3: on General page you will see "Options a the bottom of the left column
4: in the "default font" dialog select the font you want and the size for that font
5: at bottom right of the screen click OK.

you're done, and that font will stick till you change it again.

Comment: Yes, that's an improvement, Psycogeek. I will remember it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you fix it in OneNote 2010:

1. Go to Home tab
2. Under Styles scroll down using middle down arrow and select Normal
3. Click on: File -> Options -> General -> Default Font
4. Change it to what ever you want (ie. Arial 12)
5. Click Ok
6. Under Styles, make sure Normal is still highlighted
7. Click bottom down arrow, and select 'Clear Formatting'
8. Go back to your note, and the font should be as you selected in step 4. In this example Arial 12.

Good luck,
Vic